# change nested object value with a user specified path

Tags: javascript

### Problem

I want to build a function that takes in a path to a nested object value and sets that value to 'new value'

```js
const obj = {
  foo: {
    bar: 'baz'
  }
}

// api should look like
changeObjKey(o => o.foo.bar)

//or
changeObjKey('foo.bar')

/*
* expected:
obj = {
  foo: {
    bar: 'new value'
  }
}
*/
```

### What I've tried:

Something like this (which obviously doesn't work)

```
function changeObjKey(cb){
  cb(obj) = 'new value'
}
```

> I don't want to use lodash or the likes, I'm looking for the most minimal solution to this problem. I also don't want to use eval and the api should support both foo.bar and foo[bar] (if its string based)

Comment: How would the api usage just be `changeObjKey(o => o.foo.bar)`? It doesn't specify the object being passed in nor the value to change `o.foo.bar` to

Comment: @NickParsons moreover, how can it work if that resolves to a primitive type?

Comment: @NickParsons those are both fixed.